# SendMessage (Click) to ToolbarWindows32

Tags: c#, sendmessage

I'm trying to simulate a button click using `SendMessage` to a specific button, but when use tools such as spy++ or Winspy, it gives me a handle too all the ToolbarWindows32, not for every button separately.

There is a same topic [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22922176/Press-button-of-a-ToolbarWindow32.html) , but I don't know how to perform the same thing in c#.

Note : I have the handle of ToolbarWindows32.

Here’s my code that get a list of all the open windows (Including ToolbarWindows32 Handle).

```
  using HWND = IntPtr;

/// <summary>Contains functionality to get all the open windows.</summary>
public static class OpenWindowGetter
{
  /// <summary>Returns a dictionary that contains the handle and title of all the open windows.</summary>
  /// <returns>A dictionary that contains the handle and title of all the open windows.</returns>
  public static IDictionary<HWND, string> GetOpenWindows()
  {
    HWND shellWindow = GetShellWindow();
    Dictionary<HWND, string> windows = new Dictionary<HWND, string>();

    EnumWindows(delegate(HWND hWnd, int lParam)
    {
      if (hWnd == shellWindow) return true;
      if (!IsWindowVisible(hWnd)) return true;

          int length = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd);
          if (length == 0) return true;

          StringB
```

uilder builder = new StringBuilder(length);
          GetWindowText(hWnd, builder, length + 1);

```
      windows[hWnd] = builder.ToString();
      return true;

    }, 0);

    return windows;
  }

  private delegate bool EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, int lParam);

  [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
  private static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc enumFunc, int lParam);

  [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
  private static extern int GetWindowText(HWND hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

  [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
  private static extern int GetWindowTextLength(HWND hWnd);

  [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
  private static extern bool IsWindowVisible(HWND hWnd);

  [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
  private static extern IntPtr GetShellWindow();
}
```

And to use :

```
    foreach(KeyValuePair<IntPtr, string> window in OpenWindowGetter.GetOpenWindows())
{
  IntPtr handle = window.Key;
  string title = window.Value;

  Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", handle, title);
}
```

So my question is how to sendmessage (click) to the first button of a ToolbarWindows32 ?

Comment: The buttons in a ToolbarWindow32 are not themselves windows so can't be found with your pinvoke declaration.  Remarkably the MSDN docs don't say how a click notification is delivered.  [This web page](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?384158-Is-it-possible-to-programatically-simulate-toolbar-button-click) shows how another programmer struggled to find the WM_COMMAND message.  Verify with the Spy++ utility, also what you need to find the command ids for the buttons.  UI Automation is the better mouse trap.

Comment: @HansPassant - You are correct sir .... He can also, create custom a custom button object & have some kind of identifier property.  Not sure, what kind of app he's making.  So, I can't provide a proper code example.  When I made a taskmanager, I believe, each button was identified by the windows handle.